# parse.com is parse JSON? (android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've chosen to use [Parse](http://www.parse.com) as the backend for my app. Unfortunately there aren't many tutorials and only one for Android.

Does the Parse framework use JSON? If so I can learn from reading those tutorials.

I'm trying to take data from a form (including a radio button) and have it input into the database. The tutorial I've found in the Parse Android user signup guide is:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with
ParseObject user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");
```

I want to add the radio button input as text in a field like the last line in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of tutorials on the parse.com's webpage. For eg: [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide) should help you get started.

It is a 3rd party framework so you would have to refer to their official documentation to use their platform in the right manner.

It seems like parse.com uses a custom `ParseObject`: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-classes

Comment: thanks. maybe i should have added i'm an amateur programmer. for example in their guide they show an example; 'code' ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user.put("phone", "650-253-0000"); 'code' i want to be able to use the data in my form fields to fill in the name, email etc and add a field (like they've done) but populate it with text based on a radio button check.

Comment: sorry, new stackoverflow user; `ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please update your question so everyone else can also understand what problem you're facing. You will have to be specific and describe the problem in detail. For eg: I am trying to load a phone number into a text field and here's the code snippet that does this. Refer the StackOverflow FAQs here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq/